# Having Trouble InvokingMember in webbrowser in c#?

Tags: c#

```
    private void location()
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("searchInput").SetAttribute("value", "Dick's Sporting Goods");
    }

    private void pickLocation()
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("location_98229424").InvokeMember("click");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ++count;
        if (count == 1)
        {
            email = txt_email.Text;
            randomName();
            Register();

        }

        if (count == 2)
            location();
        if (count == 3)
            pickLocation();
    }
```

I'm having trouble with the function "pickLocation()".
It doesn't click! I cannot figure it out! Can anyone help me?

Comment: What kind of element is location_98229424, so you have a click handler registered to it or its containing elements

Comment: Here is the image of the html code for it. http://gyazo.com/24bc828665d2376fd1cb231d10a03090

Comment: Just in case try upper case 'Click'

Comment: You could also use invokescript on the document to call you click handler via JavaScript, webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", "$('#location_98229424').click()");

Answer (score 0):

I once built an automated form app to crawl a website, navigate and download some files automagically.

The code you are pointing out **should** work. However, you need to be more specific about the html document you are targeting. Where it could go wrong, is actually attempting to access the DOM before the window has actually loaded, therefore invoking a method on something it cannot locate could throw exceptions or simply just not fire.

You could of course be having other errors, however try this after you navigate to a page/link adding a delegate like

```
        //create a delegate for event of documeent completed to combat multiple firings of the event
        this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += delegate
        {
            if (complete)
                return;
            complete = true;
            // DocumentCompleted is fired before window.onload and body.onload
            this.webBrowser1.Document.Window.AttachEventHandler("onload", delegate
            {
                //if all awaiting threads have been fired the DOM is accessible
                System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate
                {
                    //navigate 
                    navigate("https://website.com");
                }, null);

            });
        };
        //registering new evenhandler on document complete
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
```

This will combat you trying to access the dom possibly when iFrames are being fired etc.